# How to add a blank line in a Manifest file of a jar in gradle

Tags: gradle, manifest

I need to add the data in MANIFEST.MF of jar file in below format .

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: MyService
Service-Class: com.MyService

Packaged-Jars: xmlParserAPIs jython
```

My condition is : The manifest text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return. Also, make sure to include a blank line before each class header line (e.g.lines beginning with "Name: (class file)")

What should I do in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an escaped newline character like:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Manifest-Version': 1.0 + "\n",
            'SomeOther': 'test',
            //...
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my hour!